# Find the equations of all tangent lines to the function $f(x)=x^{2}+4x-2$ that go through the point $(5,2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I have tried a few things. The tangent line does not go through the origin so there must be a value of b (in $y=mx+b$). I am not sure where to go from where I started which is finding the general equation of the derivative of $f(x)$.

Here is what I have tried:

I know that m (the slope) is equal to $2x + 4$.

From then I set two equations to equal each other (that I found by using the point slope formula of a line that goes through $(5,2)$.

Comment: Which function is it?

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far it makes it easier for us to help you. Also format your question correctly. You haven't told us what your function is either.

Comment: You havent posted any function. And just because a line goes through the point $(5,2)$ doesnt mean it cannot go through the origin.

Comment: You have $m=f'(5)$ and you can get $b$ by noticing that $(5,2)$ belongs to the tangent line.

Comment: I have added the function. I apologize.

Comment: @Surb Why does $m=f'(5)$ ? I think he is not finding the tangent line at $x=5$ but the tangent lines that go through the point $(5,2)$ (maybe there exist many tangent lines with this property).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R} }$
Given $f:I \subseteq \R \rightarrow \R$ a differentiable function, we know that an equation of a tangent line in $p \in I $ is
$
y=f(p)+f'(p)(x-p) \; .
$

Then, you have to find $p \in I$ such that the equation
$
2=f(p)+f'(p)(5-p)
$
is satisfied.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

**Another method:**

Take a line through $(5,2)$: $\;y=2+t(x-5)$, and the equation for the intersection points with the parabola: $\;y=x^2+4x-2=2+t(x-2)$, whence the equation with parameter:
$$x^2+(4-t)x+2(t-2)=0.$$
The line with slope $t$ is tangent to the curve if this equation has a double  root, which is equal to $\dfrac{t-4}2$, i.e. if
$$\Delta=(4-t)^2-8(t-2)=0.$$
As this is a quadratic equation for $t$, you'll find two lines tangent to the parabola.